# Computing two improper integrals

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

[Image of the integrals I'm asked to compute.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUBRt.jpg)

I can't understand the steps needed to compute them. Note that $b>0.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is usually better to write more about what have you tried and what exactly is the problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use integration by parts. This is a general strategy to try any time you're asked to integrate something of the form $f(x) \exp(a x + b)$, where $f(x)$ is a polynomial. Use integration by parts to keep differentiating the polynomial (and integrating the exponential) until the polynomial is gone.

Note that the first integral is of an odd function, so the main task here is to prove that the improper integral exists. If it exists, it must be zero.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me how do you know hat the first function is odd? Do you count the rank of the exponent in this case 1? I am sorry for my ignorance